# npm run cannot find module 'sass' after repeated reinstall attempts

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-mix, node-sass

Any call to `npm run` produces this error:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev /project
> npm run development


> @ development /project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:235
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Cannot find module 'sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (/project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at implementation (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Sass.js:52:39)
    at implementation (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:125:61)
    at global.tap (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at Sass.loaderOptions (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:123:9)
    at extractPlugin (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:87:39)
    at global.tap (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at details.forEach.preprocessor (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:27:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Sass.webpackRules (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:22:22)
    at ComponentFactory.applyRules (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:155:23)
    at Mix.listen.rules (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:66:48)
    at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
    at Mix.dispatch (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:119:25)
    at WebpackConfig.buildRules (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:83:13)
    at WebpackConfig.build (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:23:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:29:38)
    at Module._compile (/project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (/project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:113:13)
    at requireConfig (/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:115:6)
    at /project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:122:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:120:15)
    at yargs.parse (/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:232:39)
    at Object.parse (/project/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "fancybox": "^3.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "ladda": "^2.0.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.13",
    "locutus": "^2.0.10",
    "metismenu": "^2.7.9",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.*",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.6.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "bootstrap4c-chosen": "^1.0.13",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "imagemin": "^6.0.0",
    "jsonexport": "^2.4.1",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.32.4",
    "vue-api-query": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-events": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.3",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^1.6.3",
    "vuetable-2": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version()
    .sourceMaps();
```

I've tried deleting `node_modules` and `npm install` again but that doesn't fix it.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Doing the same process using `yarn install` instead of npm does not solve it.

Tried installing using this option but no luck: `npm install node-sass --no-bin-links`

- npm v6.4.1
- node v11.5.0
- yarn v1.12.3

This problem does not happen on older version of Webpack and Mix. For instance, the following packages work but obviously lose some of the newer features:

```
"laravel-mix": "^3",
"webpack": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since 4.0.0 `laravel-mix` [switched](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/releases/tag/v4.0.0) to using `sass` instead of `node-sass`.

Two ways to solve this issue:

1. Install `sass` npm package:

   ```
   npm -g i sass
   ```
2. Configure `mix` to use `node-sass` instead (`webpack.mix.js`):

   ```js
   mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
     implementation: require('node-sass')
   });
   ```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me it throw another error after above steps "your system doesn't support node sass yet ...'

Comment: edit : I've to install node-sass as local dependency to make above work.

Comment: @mufaddal_mw Yes, it was assumed the `node-sass` is already installed, like stated in the question.

Comment: In webpack.mix.js, I changed the code from mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps().sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');      to    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    implementation: require('node-sass')
});

Comment: Why is this not installed when a user runs npm install, isnt that the whole point of npm? to install dependancies?

Comment: @Brad Because `sass` is not a _dependency_ for `laravel-mix`. You could choose to use another SASS implementation after all, right? You could even not use it at all. So, you should install them manually.

Comment: for yarn package users --> 
"yarn add sass"

Comment: Please make sure to restart the npm debug dev server after that. 
For those that it did not work, it is probably why it did not work.

Answer (score 45):

ReactJS uses `node-sass`, run the below command.

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

Comment: Saved me a great deal of time.

Comment: can you explain why does this work please ?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue some times back but I did this and it worked

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install sass
```

This should work for you I hope

Comment: new react users-worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue some times back but I did this and it worked
**npm install sass**

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the module while your server was running, you have just to stop the server and running it again...

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above but kept seeing this when I ran `./bin/dev`:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --watch
$ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './sass.dart.js'
```

So I tried `yarn add sass` and it worked. Disclaimer: I don't fully understand npm and yarn, so I'm not quite sure *why* it worked, just that it did.